# vue.js v-model not updating if vue-range-slider component on page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem with the structure of my Vue.js components, but I don't understand what it is.

This is my `app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('search', require('./components/Search').default);
Vue.component('graph', require('./components/Graph').default);
Vue.component('account', require('./components/Account').default);
Vue.component('design-theme', require('./components/DesignTheme').default);

 const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  },
  methods: {
  },
  mounted: function () {
  },
  computed: {
  }
});
```

So I don't have any methods or anything here, it is all in the four individual components. Each component works fine on its own, but when there is more than one in a page, something is off. Consider the `Search.vue` component. It simply sends an `axios` request to the server on keyup and shows a list of results:

```
<template>
    <div class="search basic-search">
        <input type="text" v-model="search_string" v-on:keyup="search" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search" value=""/>
        <div :class="['search-results', active === true ? 'active' : '']">
            <div class="search-result" v-for="result in search_results" v-on:click="submit(result.id)">
                {{ result.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                search_string : '',
                search_results : [],
                active : false
            };
        },

        methods : {
            search : function() {
                const axios_data = {
                    _token  : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                    str : this.search_string
                };

                axios.post('/search', axios_data).then(response => {

                    if(response.data.success){
                        this.search_results = response.data.stocks;
                        this.active = true;
                    }

                });
            },

            submit : function(stock_id) {
                document.location = "/graphs/" + stock_id;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This works fine if the `Graph.vue` component is not included on the page. But, if it is, then `search_str` always remains empty, even though the `search` method is called on `keyup`.

There are no errors in the console - it's just that `search_string` remains empty when I type (as does the input field).

Perhaps I don't understand something on a conceptual level in Vue.js, but I can't figure out the relation here, or how to adapt the code to this situation.

This is the problematic part of the `Graph` component, if this is removed then the search works OK.

```
<vue-range-slider v-model="range" :min="0" :max="100" v-on:drag-end="updateRange"></vue-range-slider>
```

This is the component in question:

https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider

Another interesting side effect (that I just noticed) is that, when this component is on the page, it is impossible to select text with the mouse. It seems like the component is somehow hijacking events, but I don't understand how.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console when there is more than one in a page?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. It's just that search_str remains empty when I type (as does the input field).

Comment: Can you show the Graph.vue compoent?

Comment: Try deleting `value=""` from the input.

Comment: See a couple of issues with your code. Try using the right style (https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-name-casing-strongly-recommended). Also the function calling axios should be async.

Comment: @AdamOrlov Graph.vue is quite big, any particular part you are interested in? I've deleted `value=""` from the input now, but that didn't help.

Comment: @jovan yes, show the `data` from graph. Did you try to reproduce this? I might take a look at it.

Comment: @AdamOrlov I've added data from `Graph.vue` to the question. I haven't tried to reproduce it outside the context of the app, but the correlation is pretty clear - it works on every page except that one, and in that one `Graph` is the only other component.

Comment: @jovan thanks for update. I checked and I don't see any errors you could do. I know you probably did but did you double check for a simple typo? In a question you once used `search_str`... maybe that's the case... Sorry mate I have no other idea. Looks like you did everything right. Any way I mark it as interested.

Comment: @AdamOrlov Thanks for trying anyway. Yeah the search_str is just a typo in the question, not in the code...I'll post here when I figure this out.

Comment: 2 new thoughts. 1. Maybe there is something wrong with `data` property merging. Did you try deleting the `data` in main component, or change the order of components? Can you add the "Search" Component after the "Graph"? 2. Did you check Vue-devtools? Is there the event `@input` firing while you are typing?

Comment: @AdamOrlov I have found the root cause of the problem, it is an imported component within `Graph`. I have added the code and the GitHub link for that component to the question above. Can you have a look?

Comment: Have you already tried the suggested quickfixe from one of their [github issue](https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider/pull/5)?

Comment: @Uchendu I don't understand how/where to apply the fix. I understand that I need to remove `stopPropagation` from some events (`keyUp` in my case) but I am not sure what the process is since the component is hosted on GitHub and apparently they are not updating it. I'd gladly accept an answer that guides me through it step by step.

Comment: @jovan awesome! Gr8 You solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you identified correctly, the Vue Range Slider component is intercepting the events. There is an open merge request on their [github page](https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider/pull/5).

As suggested in the referenced issues, you should change this line in your `package.json` file:

```
"vue-range-component": "^1.0.3",
```

To this one:

```
"vue-range-component": "Anoesj/vue-range-slider#master",
```

However, since this is not the default branch of the plugin, you should frequently check the issue on github and switch back to the official branch as soon as the merge request passes.

Comment: But doesn't that just fix the keydown event? If I want to fix my keyup problem, should I make a fork of my own and fix it there?

Comment: It seems to work with your input element and a dummy `search` method bound to the keyup event. If you still have it does not solve your problem, you would have to setup your project in a (Sandbox)[https://codesandbox.io/s/] or something similar.

Comment: I had a quick look at the code and changes commited of the plugin. From my point of view, the [code handling the keyup](https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider/blob/728fd85745d2a244e7d6d72dd5237ad159b40a06/src/js/vue-range-slider.js#L1078) looks fine.

Comment: I have tried that change in package.json, and I tried running npm install again, but nothing changes. Still the same issue.

Comment: My last guess is to remove the plugin manually, clean your browser cache and then make again the npm install and serve the app. If that doesn't do the trick, you should provide your code in a sandbox so I could inspect your case, since the solution solves the problem on my dummy version.

Comment: Scratch that - it works with the fix, I just needed to recompile some assets on my end. I have accepted your answer, I can't award the bounty yet so I will do it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211286/discussion-between-uchendu-and-jovan).